# Error creating bean with name '...' defined in file

Tags: java, spring, maven, model-view-controller

can anyone help me with this

I used IntelliJ Idea Ultimate with Spring MVC and DAO

Error message:

```
"/media/vlad/36BCE079BCE034D1/Tomcat 7.0.62/bin/catalina.sh" run
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
[2015-07-07 11:05:09,425] Artifact SibiuNewsAggregator:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.62
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          May 7 2015 17:14:55 UTC
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.62.0
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            3.19.0-21-generic
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_45-b14
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/vlad/.IntelliJIdea14/system/tomcat/Unnamed_SibiuNewsAggregator
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /media/vlad/36BCE079BCE034D1/Tomcat 7.0.62
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/vlad/.IntelliJIdea14/system/tomcat/Unnamed_SibiuNewsAggregator/conf/logging.properties
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/media/vlad/36BCE079BCE034D1/Tomcat 7.0.62/endorsed
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/vlad/.IntelliJIdea14/system/tomcat/Unnamed_SibiuNewsAggregator
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/media/vlad/36BCE079BCE034D1/Tomcat 7.0.62
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/media/vlad/36BCE079BCE034D1/Tomcat 7.0.62/temp
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /home/vlad/IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4(Linux)/bin::/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 725 ms
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.62
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 65 ms
Connected to server
[2015-07-07 11:05:10,607] Artifact SibiuNewsAggregator:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/media/vlad/36BCE079BCE034D1/iQuest_project/iQuest_project_final/iQuest_final_3/Project/target/SibiuNewsAggregator/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:12 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:12 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Jul 07 11:05:12 EEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:12 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/database-config.xml]
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:12 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DBCTemplate' defined in file [/media/vlad/36BCE079BCE034D1/iQuest_project/iQuest_project_final/iQuest_final_3/Project/target/SibiuNewsAggregator/WEB-INF/classes/com/iquest/news/dao/DBCTemplate.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.iquest.news.dao.DBCTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1809)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$241(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/1334101548.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.iquest.news.dao.DBCTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1088)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
    at com.iquest.news.dao.DBCTemplate.<init>(DBCTemplate.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 61 more



Jul 07, 2015 11:05:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
[2015-07-07 11:05:12,959] Artifact SibiuNewsAggregator:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /media/vlad/36BCE079BCE034D1/Tomcat 7.0.62/webapps/manager
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jul 07, 2015 11:05:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /media/vlad/36BCE079BCE034D1/Tomcat 7.0.62/webapps/manager has finished in 73 ms
```

And here are my classes:
DCBTemplate:

```
package com.iquest.news.dao;

import com.iquest.news.model.Author;
import com.iquest.news.model.Category;
import com.iquest.news.model.News;
import com.iquest.news.model.Statistics;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class DBCTemplate<T> implements DAO<T> {

    private Class<T> clazz;

    public DBCTemplate() {
        final Type type = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        final ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) type;
        clazz = (Class) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void add(T news) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(news);
    }

    @Override
    public T getItem(long id) {
        T news = (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(clazz.getClass(), id);
        return news;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("JpaQlInspection")
    @Override
    public List<T> getAll() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from" + clazz.getName()).list();
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(long id) {
        T news = getItem(id);
        if (news != null)
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(news);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(long id, T newNews) {
        if (newNews instanceof News) {
            News oldNews = (News) getItem(((News) newNews).getId());
            oldNews.setTitle(((News) newNews).getTitle());
            oldNews.setSubtitle(((News) newNews).getSubtitle());
            oldNews.setDescription(((News) newNews).getDescription());
            oldNews.setStart_date(((News) newNews).getStart_date());
            oldNews.setEnd_date(((News) newNews).getEnd_date());
            oldNews.setAuthor_id(((News) newNews).getAuthor_id());
            oldNews.setCategory_id(((News) newNews).getCategory_id());
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(oldNews);
        }
        else if(newNews instanceof Author){
            Author oldNews = (Author) getItem(((Author) newNews).getId());
            oldNews.setName(((Author) newNews).getName());
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(oldNews);
        }
        else if(newNews instanceof Category){
            Category oldNews = (Category) getItem(((Category) newNews).getId());
            oldNews.setName(((Category) newNews).getName());
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(oldNews);
        }
        else if(newNews instanceof Statistics){
            Statistics oldNews = (Statistics) getItem(((Statistics) newNews).getId());
            oldNews.setLast_scanned(((Statistics) newNews).getLast_scanned());
            oldNews.setUrl(((Statistics) newNews).getUrl());
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(oldNews);
        }
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

XML for beans:

```
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.iquest.news.controller"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="com.iquest.news.dao.DBCTemplate" id = "DBCTemplate"/>
</beans>
```

So that's my problem, can anyone show me how I can fix it? 
Thx in advance

Comment: Probably I didn't understood the question, but I see generics, Spring doesn't work with generics properly. Guice is better.

Comment: This kind of issue come when there are incompatible JAR versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access your type parameters from interface in java. Any generic type resolution in Java, always required that the type arguments be captured in a type definition.

You should make DBCTemplate an abstract and make a new implementation of it. Than your code will work like a charm. Here is an example

```
//@Repository
public abstract class DBCTemplate<T> implements DAO<T> {
// Same as before
}
```

And then define a new specialised DBCTemplate. Lets say your entity is News. Here is your working template.

```
@Repository // Spring can init this 
public class NewsDBCTemplate extends DBCTemplate<News> {
// Put your News ( or other entity) based operations here
}
```